# How To Change Scrollbar Action In GNOME 3.10

Tags: gnome, scrolling, gtk3

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 which includes GNOME 3.10.

I would like to change the default method / action xwindows takes when I click on a scrollbar above or below the slider.

Currently it moves to the position in the file / object that corresponds to the point on the slider where you clicked.  IMHO, this makes the slider button redundant.

I would prefer that the window behave as though I have hit page up or page down on my keyboard.

Comment: People looking for a way https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrollbar.html should help.

Comment: For what it's worth, _right-clicking_ on the scroll bar has the old behaviour of scrolling one page up or down.

Answer (score 6):

The setting you're looking for is [`gtk-primary-button-warps-slider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-primary-button-warps-slider):

> Whether a click in a GtkRange trough should scroll to the click position or scroll by a single page in the respective direction.
>
> Flags: Read / Write
>
> Default value: TRUE

`TRUE` means "*scroll to the click position*" and `FALSE` means "*scroll by a single page*".

To change the setting, edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add the following line:

`gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=0`

Restart your GTK3 apps to pick up the change.

FYI: I've encountered some flaky behavior in scrolling after changing the setting, but I don't know if it was the setting or the app itself.

Comment: Thanks for this.  But I needed another detail to get this working for me, and it's not obvious from the answer or the linked documentation page: the line needs to be in a section with the heading `[Settings]`