# Scrollbar moves to where I click

Tags: mouse, gtk, scrolling

I use MATE on Fedora.  At some point, the behavior of scrollbars on many applications has changed.  When I click below a scrollbar, now the scrollbar jumps to where I clicked.  Previously, it used to page down by one page (if I clicked anywhere below the current location of the scrollbar).

I preferred the old behavior.  When on a very long page, the new behavior tends to make the scrollbar almost unusable: I can't control where I click precisely enough to control where the page jumps to.

Is there a way to regain the previous behavior?  In other words, is there a way to make clicking on a scrollbar, below the current location of the scroll, to cause the window to go down by one page, rather than jumping to where I clicked?

This difference is most noticeable in Firefox, but is not limited solely to Firefox; it affects other applications, too.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be anything specific to MATE or Fedora. I recently started noticing the same annoying change in behavior, and I use fluxbox on Mint.

Comment: Earlier: [How To Change Scrollbar Action In GNOME 3.10](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182186/13260).

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue on Firefox 48, and [this answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125603) worked for me:

> Create `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add
>
> ```
> [Settings]
> gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
> ```

I'm using XFCE, but Firefox is reading that setting for some reason. It also worked with other Gnome 3 applications, such as `gnome-todo`.

After creating that file, I only had to restart Firefox and its behavior was modified (no need to reboot).

Comment: Works for Firefox 50 too.

Comment: Thank you, they used to have a setting in about:config which they have taken away in later versions. you saved the day with this.

Comment: Thanks, this actually impacts most apps in Linux Mint Cinnamon, such as Nemo file manager, Terminal, Firefox, etc!

Comment: this works in xubuntu, firefox 50. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You get the old page-up/down behavior via right-clicking on the scroll bar.

Comment: Is there any way to swap these actions in a config file? Make the old behaviour the default left-click, and make jump-to-location work with right-click?

Comment: Right-clicking simply seems to scroll very slowly. Useful for very precise scrolling.

Comment: Middle click did the trick for me

Comment: @Mastiff on which distribution/GnomeShell version? Middle-clicking on the Firefox  scroll bar doesn't do anything using a Fedora 31 box of mine (GnomeShell in Wayland mode). Whereas right-clicking still works as described for me.

Comment: Sorry for vagueness.  In my case I was concerned with the gnome terminal. My version says 3.28.2

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure of the general case , but in **FireFox**, there is a configuration setting **ui.scrollToClick=0** , which gives the behaviour you want.
If **ui.scrollToClick=1** , then clicking the scrollbar will make it jump to that point.
Also, you can use **shift-click** for getting the opposite behaviour of the current FireFox setting.

Comment: Shift-click still working in 68.0, not ui.scrollToClick=0

Answer (score 3):

You get the page-up/down behavior via shift-clicking on the scroll bar.

H/T to Laurent G.'s comment on another answer.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, please take the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and check the posting protocol, as well as how reference other posts by linking.